# loading css with block in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to load block for CSS in Django. However for some reason it doesn't work. 
my template :

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Some Title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
Some Content
{% endblock %}
```

And below is the upper part of base.html file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- This line below is the base styling, whereas the css file I'm trying to load is a specific styling for a specific page. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base.css' %}">
    {% block css %}
    {% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

I have the right css file at the right directory, but it is not reflected at all. 
I don't see what I've done wrong. I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Hi Ryan.  "It does not work" is not a full problem description.  Do you mean that you get an error or that your "<link rel..." doesn't appear in the rendered page?  Do the title blocks and content blocks render OK?  Are you testing this locally with Django's built-in webserver or remotely?   Does base.css get loaded fully?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the confusion. So it's not that I'm  getting error messages, but I don't see any stylings loaded on my page.

Comment: Then you should use Right click -> Inspect source to see whether the `<link rel...` has made it into the html.  If it has but the styling hasn't taking effect then you should try putting the href= part into your browser url to see if the file is actually being served by the webserver.  If not, it could be a typo or an issue with the way Django handles staticfiles.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find what the problem was. Appreciate it :)